# How to hide IP from 404 awk report when last value has only 2 digits

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a script that looks for 404 HTTP status codes in my access log. However, the security team has a script that is searching for vulnerabilities which causes 100's of 404 entries in my logs. I filter out the IP address of their test boxes to avoid false positives. But they added a new server recently. The problem is that the IP address of this new server only has 2 digits for the last part. (ie. 10.1.1.18 - that isn't the IP, but you get the idea).

How do I get awk or grep to ignore the IP ending 18 and not the valid IPs 180-189 that I need to search for?

For those unfamiliar with the contents of an HTTP access log, I give this example:

> 10.1.1.18 - - [12/May/2018:01:25:07 -0600] "GET /xampp/cgi.cgi HTTP/1.1" 404 909

I have tried quoting the IP address to include the space after the 18 like this:

> cat access.log | grep -v "10.10.10.230" | grep -v "10.10.11.116" | grep -v "10.1.1.18 " | awk -f report_errors.awk

But then I don't get any output from the awk script. Why would having a space in the quoted grep exclusion cause the awk to die? When I remove the awk command from the end I do get the correct contents of the access.log (meaning the test server entries have been correctly removed.)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Below is the report_errors.awk file:

```
BEGIN {
  FS = "\""
  title = "HTTP sslaccess_log:\n"
  flag = 0
  error = 0
  error400 = 0
  error408 = 0
  error500 = 0
  site = 0
  separator = ""
  allERRORS = ""
}
function qsortA(array,min,max) {
  if (min > max) {
    return
  }

  m = min
  for (knx = (min + 1) ; knx <= max ; knx++) {
    if (array[knx] < array[min]) {
      swap(array,++m,knx)
      swap(array,min,m)
    }
  }
  qsortA(array,min,(m - 1))
  qsortA(array,(m + 1),max)
}

function swap(array,ind1,ind2) {
 sw = array[ind1]
 array[ind1] = array[ind2]
 array[ind2] = sw
}

$3 ~ / 404 / {
  printf( "%s", title)
  if ( $2 ~ /site/ || $2 ~ /dot.gif/ || $2 ~ /maintenance/ || $2 ~ /graypixel.gif/ || $2 ~ /.css/ || $2 ~ /crossdomain.xml/  || $2 ~ /OPTIONS/ )
  {
    split( $2, name, " " )
    msg = substr(name[1],0,1) " " name[2]
    if ( index( allERRORS, msg) == 0 )
    {
      allERRORS = allERRORS separator msg
      separator = ","
    }
    arrCOUNT[msg]++
    site=1
  }
  else
  {
    print " - " $0
    error++
  }
  title = ""
  flag++
}
$3 ~ / 400 / {
  error400++
}
$3 ~ / 408 / {
  error408++
}
$3 ~ / 500 / {
# printf( "%s", title)
# print " - " $0
  error500++
# title = ""
# flag++
}
END {
  if (flag > 0) {
    if (error > 0) {
      printf("---- %4d: basic errors\n", error)
      printf("---- %4d: 400 errors\n", error400)
      printf("---- %4d: 408 errors\n", error408)
      printf("---- %4d: 500 errors\n", error500)
    }
    if (site = 1)
    {
      split( allERRORS, arrERRORS, "," )
      jnx = 0
      for ( inx in arrERRORS )
      {
        arrNew[++jnx] = arrERRORS[inx]
      }
      qsortA(arrNew,1,jnx)
      inx = 0
      while ( inx < jnx )
      {
        printf("---- %4d: %s\n",arrCOUNT[arrNew[++inx]],arrNew[inx])
      }
    }
    printf("---- %4d: Total 404 Errors\n",flag)
  }
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip an IP address that ends in 2 digits:

```
/^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]{2}[[:space:]]/ { next }
```

btw this:

```
cat access.log | grep -v "10.10.10.230" | grep -v "10.10.11.116" | grep -v "10.1.1.18 " | awk 'foo'
```

needs to have its RE metachars escaped:

```
cat access.log | grep -v "10\.10\.10\.230" | grep -v "10\.10\.11\.116" | grep -v "10\.1\.1\.18 " | awk 'foo'
```

and should actually be written as just:

```
awk '/10\.10\.10\.220|10\.10\.11\.116|10\.1\.1\.18 /{next} foo' access.log
```

but I suspect what you really want might be:

```
awk '/^10\.(10\.10\.(220|116)|1\.1\.18[[:space:]])/{next} foo' access.log
```

Comment: If I can ask - What does the {next} provide?

Comment: LOL, thanks for not just saying "ask Google - not me". I appreciate your time more than you might know.

Answer (score 0):

To get the all logs containing 404 errors skipping those that have IP addresses ending with 2 digits using grep :

```
$ grep 404 access.log | grep -v '\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d\d[^0-9]'
```